# how to hardcode sertain datetimes from now for five years ahead

Tags: mysql

I'm not very advanced in SQL and hope that someone can help me with one query. I'm building a booking platform in React with backend and API in Symfony. So I have starttime, endtime (will be calculated automatically with DATEADD depends on the duration of the chosen service), I will calculate avaliable timeslots to offer the new bookings (with DATEDIFF).

It seems all possible only in case if I'll have an additional table "Agenda_timeslots" with its own starttime,
endtime and
index - [0]free, [1]booked or [2]not available. So each service depends on its fixed duration will take some certain number of timeslots in this agenda.

So my question is - how to write query to generate such table with conditions - timeslots by 20min start from 9am till 5pm only from Monday to Friday for the next five years. If i'll have this timelots, I can loop through it and use SQL formulas. I believe there should be the way than to do it manually

Or I don't need timeslots at all? Only time from 9am to 5pm and the calculate only available hours in between booking time, to see if requested service will fit in the free time gap?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Create static service table in your database with this data for reasonable period and use it as rowsource.  Or 2 service tables - one with dates from Monday to Friday for reasonable period, another with timeslots from 9am till 5pm - this will be more compact. Or use recursive CTE and generate needed data (if your server version allows).

Comment: Do you mean to fill rows one by one manually? Manually I can. My question is if there is a way to generate it automatically.

Comment: *My question is if there is a way to generate it automatically.* ?? As I have said already: use recursive CTE and generate needed data (if your server version allows).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I missed "recursive CTE" because I never heard about it before. But thx for a hint, at least I know what to search now

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE 
odd_no (sr_no, n) AS
(
SELECT 1, 1 
union all
SELECT sr_no+1, n+2 from odd_no where sr_no < 5 
)
SELECT * FROM odd_no;

Answer (score 0):

> timeslots by 20min start from 9am till 5pm only from Monday to Friday for the next five years.

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT @start_date `date`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM cte1 WHERE `date` < @end_date ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT CAST('09:00' AS TIME) `time`
          UNION ALL
          SELECT `time` + INTERVAL 20 minute FROM cte2 WHERE `time` < '17:00' )
SELECT TIMESTAMP(cte1.`date`, cte2.`time`) `datetime`
FROM cte1
CROSS JOIN cte2
WHERE WEEKDAY(cte1.`date`) < 5
```

For provided conditions `SET @end_date := @start_date + INTERVAL 5 YEAR`.